# code does not insert all elements of array to string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i have this code which should insert all elements of array which is some html on random places in a string. but it only inserts last element to that string. please help

```
Random insertPos = new Random();
int pos = insertPos.Next(txtInput.Text.Length);
int firSpace= txtInput.Text.IndexOf(" ", pos);
int secSpace = txtInput.Text.IndexOf(" ", firSpace+1);
int wLen = secSpace - firSpace;<br/>
string word = txtInput.Text.Substring(firSpace,wLen);
foreach (string url in urlArray)
{
    txtOutput.Text = 
         txtInput.Text.Replace(word, "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + word + "</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing (`=`) the contents of `txtOutput.Text` on every iteration so of course you are only going to see the last result. Consider using `+=`<sup>1</sup> first to get it working and then a `StringBuilder` if your performance is suffering and this is a bottleneck.

<sup>1</sup>: It's not clear exactly how you want it formatted, but at least `+=` will append and assign the result of the append instead of just the result of the current iteration.

Comment: my problem is, i have a string, say 200 words long, have an array which contains urls, say 4 urls. i want to embed those urls in string at random places, if i use <code>+=</code> it creates as many copies of original string as i have urls in array and embeds html around same word in all copies.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the Text property of the textbox in every step of the foreach loop. Only the result of last loop will be left.

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly saying "figure out what happens when I insert the HTML into `txtInput` 's text, and assign the result to the `txtOutput` text". But this does not actually change the text in `txtInput`, so you are starting fresh each time; and you throw away the `txtOutput` text each time to replace it with the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaison said you are using `=` instead of `+=`, but there are better solutions. Remember that strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Use string.Format or StringBuilder where you're concatenating strings. Examples:

```
string[] strArray = {"a", "b", "c"};
string word = "word";

//1st solution +=
string output = "";

foreach (string str in strArray)
    output += "<a href=\"" + str + "\">" + word + "</a>";

Console.WriteLine(output);

//better solution string.Format
output = "";

foreach (string str in strArray)            
    output += string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", str, word);

Console.WriteLine(output);

//StringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string str in strArray)            
    sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", str, word);

output = sb.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(output);

//linq & string.Join
output = string.Join("", strArray.Select( str => string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", str, word)).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(output);

Console.Read();
```